# PubSubClient & ArduinoJSON - Arduino passing char to digitalWrite

Tags: variables, arduino, type-conversion

I am not sure how to pass the values in the function in order to be used within the `digitalWrite` functions.

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: cannot convert 'String' to 'uint8_t' {aka unsigned char}' for argument '1' to 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'
```

**pubsub callback**

```cpp
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("New message on [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  Serial.println("");
  char s[length];

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    s[i]=payload[i];
  }

  StaticJsonBuffer<500> jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(s);
  if (!root.success()) {
    Serial.println("parseObject() failed");
  }

  String relay = root["relay"]; // "relayOne"
  int time = root["timestamp"]; // 1351824120
  String trigger = root["trigger"]; // "ON"

  // Feel free to add more if statements to control more GPIOs with MQTT
  commander(relay, trigger);

}
```

**commander function**

```cpp
void commander(String relay, String trigger) {

  if(trigger == "ON"){
      Serial.print("Turning ");
      Serial.println(relay);
      Serial.println(" on");
      digitalWrite(relay, HIGH);
  } else if(trigger == "OFF"){
      Serial.println(relay);
      digitalWrite(relayOne, LOW);
      Serial.print("TRIGGERED!");
  } else {
      // turn all the LEDs off:
      for (int pin = 0; pin < relayPinCount; pin++) {
        digitalWrite(relayPins[pin], LOW);
      }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
void commander(String relay, String trigger) {

  uint8_t pinNo;
  if ( relay == "relayOne" ) {
    pinNo = RELAY_1_PIN;
  } else
  if ( relay == "anotherRelay" ) {
    pinNo = OTHER_RELAY_PIN;
  } else 
  if ( ... ) {
    ...
  } else {
    return;
  }

  if(trigger == "ON"){
      Serial.print("Turning ");
      Serial.println(relay);
      Serial.println(" on");
      digitalWrite(pinNo, HIGH);
  } else if(trigger == "OFF"){
      Serial.println(relay);
      digitalWrite(pinNo, LOW);
      Serial.print("TRIGGERED!");
  } else {
      // turn all the LEDs off:
      for (int pin = 0; pin < relayPinCount; pin++) {
        digitalWrite(relayPins[pin], LOW);
      }
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I’ll try this out later on tonight. By any chance would you have some reading material to better understand what’s going on here? Does any value passed to digitalWrite need to be of that datatype? @JimmyB

Comment: WOW! This was it! Thanks alot, I'm so relieved.